# Spring integration multiple poller

Tags: spring-integration

I have an integration which has two different integration flows. So, i've divided these flows into two different classes. Let's say first integration flows has to work every two hour, and other one every one hour.

```
    // Class1
    @Bean
    public PollerMetadata poller1() {
        return Pollers.fixedRate(2, TimeUnit.HOURS, 1).get();
    }

    // Class2
    @Bean
    public PollerMetadata poller2() {
        return Pollers.fixedRate(1, TimeUnit.HOURS, 1).get();
    }
```

With this implementation, application run fails, because of *no default poller is available within the context*.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point to one of your `PollerMetadata` beans from the perspective place. 
If you talk about an `IntegrationFlow` and some endpoint polling one of those queues, then there is a respective option, e.g.:

```
.handle(..., e -> e.poller(PollerMetadata))
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-endpoints